# How to update field on parent contact record

Tags: trigger

In the following trigger, it gets child records of a custom object based on the contact id of a record that was just saved. I need to update their data into a field on the parent contact record.

The field on the contact record is named Related_Staff_Positions__c  and it is a long text field.

I.e. if 3 child records were returned, I need to clear the Related_Staff_Positions__c field, and then add each record on a separate line in the Related_Staff_Positions__c   field such that line 1 shows first name, last name role line 2 same thing line 3 same etc.

What do I add in the second for loop below?

```
trigger trgr_Related_Staff_Position on Related_Staff_Positions__c (after insert,after update,after delete) 
{


List<String> contactIds = new List<String>();    

List<Related_Staff_Positions__c> rsp_List = new List<Related_Staff_Positions__c>();    
rsp_List = [Select Contact__c , first_name__c, last_name__c from Related_Staff_Positions__c where Id IN: Trigger.New];

for(Related_Staff_Positions__c rsp : rsp_List){
    contactIds.add(rsp.Contact__c);
}

List<Related_Staff_Positions__c> otherChildren = [Select Contact__c , first_name__c, last_name__c from Related_Staff_Positions__c where Id IN: contactIds];

for(Related_Staff_Positions__c rsp : otherChildren){

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern I would use for the insert and update is this:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Related_Staff_Positions__c (after insert, after update) {
    Map<Id, Contact> m = new Map<Id, Contact>();
    // Find the parent contacts
    for (Related_Staff_Positions__c rsp: Trigger.new) {
        m.put(rsp.Contact__c, new Contact(
                Id = rsp.Contact__c,
                Related_Staff_Positions__c = ''
                ));
    }
    // Query all child objects and re-build the text in the parent contacts
    for (Related_Staff_Positions__c> rsp : [
            Select Contact__c, first_name__c, last_name__c
            from Related_Staff_Positions__c
            where Contact__c in :m.keySet()
            order by CreatedDate
            ]) {
        Contact c = m.get(rsp.Contact__c);
        c.Related_Staff_Positions__c += rsp.first_name__c + ' ' + rsp.last_name__c + '\n';
    }
    update m.values();
}
```

The delete case will need to use `Trigger.old`.

Comment: Hi Keith, the code works great. Now that I am trying to understand it...1) what is update m.values saving, the resetting Related_Staff_Positions__c  to being empty? 2) When does the c.Related_Staff_Positions__c  +=...line get saved? 3) in your line m.put(rsp.Contact__c, new Contact(
                Id = rsp.Contact__c,
                Related_Staff_Positions__c = ''
                )); why does "new Contact" achieve? You're not creating a new contact

Comment: @ApexN-u-b 1) It is updating the Contact object instances to the database. 2) When the `update m.values();` is done. 3) This line adds a new (in memory only) Contact object to a map keyed by the Contact ID. Using the map ensures there will only ever be one Contact object per Contact ID in memory ready for when the update is done.

Comment: A common pattern in Apex is to create collections in memory and manipulate those e.g. appending to the text field. Once the in-memory objects are fully updates they are then committed to the database using an insert or update.